# Zero downtime deployment Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

I've got some doubts about deploying Spring Cloud Gateway (old Zuul) with Kubernetes and getting zero-downtime. I'm completely new to Kubernetes and I'm a bit lost with quite a lot of concepts.

We would like to use the Spring Cloud Gateway verify the JWT. I've also read that when I've got a call, it should go first have gateway, afterwards the ribbon discovery and finally the REST services.

The application has very strict zero-downtime requirements. My question is, what happens when I need to redeploy for some reason the Gateway? Is it possible to achieve the zero-downtime if it is my first component and I will have constantly traffic and request in my system

Is there any other component I should set-up in order to archive this? The users that are having having access to my REST services shouldn't be disconnected abruptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes Deployments use a rolling update model to achieve zero downtime deploys. New pods are brought up and allowed to become ready, then added to the rotation, then old ones are shut down, repeat as needed.

Comment: For just a millisecond I receive an error in Spring Cloud Gateway `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:155)`